# Issue in clearcase --adding files to source control

Tags: clearcase

i m trying to add files from CCRC WAN(clearcase eclipse client ),It is not accepting for the same .
I want to add those files directly  to the server to a particular config spec .

please help me with the steps .

Comment: "It is not accepting for the same" for the same what? What the OS your your CCRC client? What is the OS and version of the ClearCase server?

Comment: i m using windows as OS for CCRC client and my clearcase server is at solaris 10 .

Comment: "It is not accepting for the same": is this 2 files with the same names and different cases? What error message do you see?

Comment: It sometimes happens that some of the files are not accepted by CCRC WAN , so we directly place them to the server ,

Comment: "are not accepted";: what error message do you see?